# Python - installing urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to use `urllib` (for backward compatibility), but I always get an error when running the script.
I tried installing `urllib` but got this error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for urllib
```

Python version - 2.7.16

this is the import part in the script which fails:

```
from urllib import request, parse
from urllib import error as urllib_error
```

import error:
`ImportError: cannot import name request`

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

From the 2.7 documentation :

> The urllib module has been split into parts and renamed in Python 3 to urllib.request, urllib.parse, and urllib.error.

So if you are trying to import urllib.request, parse and error separately - that constructs are available in Python 3.x version.

Please go through the documentation for 2.7 at : https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html

Or upgrade to latest verion of Python 3.x to import the way you have described in your post.

Answer (score 1):

You should import like this:
Download latest version of python from [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.1/python-3.9.1-amd64.exe)

```
import urllib.request,urllib.parse, urllib.error
```

Comment: getting this `unresolved import 'urllib'Python(unresolved-import)`

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: Python version - 2.7.16

Comment: try newer version

Comment: because urilib is discontinued for 2.7 versions

Answer (score 0):

There is no urllib.request module in Python 2, that module only exists in Python 3, You can use urllib2 and Request:

```
from urllib2 import Request
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my environment was configured to use Python2 and not Python3, once I resolved this, the import worked as expected.